# SSD not intended for server use?

Tags: ssd, hyper-v, windows-server-2012-r2

I bought 2x Kingston HyperX 3K SSD to use as RAID of a Hyper-V Server 2012 R2-install. When I look at the box it says "This SSD is designed for use in desktop and notebook computer workloads and is not intended for Server environments." It can also be read here: http://www.kingston.com/us/ssd/hyperx

Why's that? And when it is "not intended", does it mean that it wasn't produced with servers in mind, but please go ahead and try if you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this has to do with the expected lifespan of SSD as there is only a finite number of writes that can be made.  Under desktop/laptop operating conditions, the manufacturer has a pretty good idea of what typical usage looks like, and therefore can make a fairly good estimate on the lifespan of the drive in this environment.

Servers on the other hand tend to do a lot more work than desktops as their model is generally many clients to one server.  This could equate to a higher degree of disk writes and therefore the SDD would not last as long.

There's an interesting and fairly up to date discussion on Lifehacker here;

http://lifehacker.com/every-modern-ssd-has-a-far-far-far-longer-expected-li-826840082

Comment: I believe your explaination puts it best.  The statement basicaly translates into "We didn't test and/or benchmark our product in a server environment".

Comment: Cheers! I believe it'll work just fine for a while then. It's worth a go. If it crashes within a year I'll be sure to let you all know.